# LDO Bypass and Output Capacitors

Tags: capacitance, decoupling-capacitor, ldo

I'm using an [XC6210B332MR-G](https://www.torexsemi.com/file/xc6210/XC6210.pdf) 3.3v LDO and I want to ensure good resistance to transient ringing at boot. The datasheet stipulates a bypass and output capacitance of at least 1uF for 1.8+v output. Would there be any downsides to using a 22uF X5R MLCC? I've done some research and from what I understand, larger capacitance values will help reduce the load transient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A larger capacitor is likely to have somewhat worse high-frequency performance than a smaller cap, so I’d suggest using a 22u in parallel with the recommended 1u.  Depending on the load characteristics you might consider a 10n cap in parallel too.  You’ll want the 1u cap closest to the regulator.  The data sheet doesn’t indicate any issues with using a larger capacitance, and indeed it’s recommended for loads with big transients.  X5R is a good choice of dielectric for this application.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by ‘good’ transient response - do you want a fast rise-time, good EMC characteristics, resistance to ringing?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question to stipulate that `good resistance to transient ringing` is what I'd like to ensure.